# combine 2 text files with different number of rows in to csv file

Tags: shell

I have 2 text files as below

A.txt (with 2 rows):

```
abc-1234
tik-3456
```

B.txt (with 4 rows)

```
123456
234567
987
12
```

I want to combine these 2 to get the below file in CSV format:

```
column-1 column-2    
abc-1234 123456
tik-3456 234567
         987
         12
```

I am trying below command. However, not achieving the above result.

```
paste -d "," A.txt B.txt > C.csv
```

It is giving below output:

```
abc-1234
,123456
tik-3456,234567
,987
,12
```

Can anyone please let me know, what I am missing here?

Comment: your expected output doesn't have a comma, what do you want exactly?

Comment: My guess is that your A.txt contains a ^M or something similar at the end of the first line. Try to recreate the file

Comment: @AndreGelinas: Right, your pointer helped me. A.txt was somehow having ^M character and that was causing the problem. I fixed it and it is working now. Thanks, Andre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux we have one utility that does one think very good. So:

- paste merges files
- column with -t creates tables

The following:

```
paste -d',' /tmp/1 /tmp/2 | column -t -N 'column-1,column-2' -s',' -o' '
```

outputs the desired result.